# bootstrap class active for labels as button-checkboxes not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

## html

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <label class="btn" for="id_bar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="1" id="id_bar" />
        Bar
    </label>
    <label class="btn" for="id_open">
        <input type="checkbox" name="open" value="1" id="id_open" />
        Open now
    </label>
</div>
```

## script

```
var searchForm = $('.main-search-form');
var labels = $(searchForm).find('label');
try {
    $(labels).on({
        click: function () {
            var item = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').parent();
            $(item).addClass('active');
            alert('test');
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

## doubt

i am using **twitter bootstrap.**  when label is clicked  , obviously **test** text pops up as alert , during that time label has the class **active** but as soon as i close the alert box , label class **active** vanishes , please help

Comment: did you use Firebug to see that the css class will be removed or another css class did disable one?

Comment: no , i dint understand your explanation , please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured that out ,

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
```

just removed the attribute data-toggle , and its all fine now

but again the toggleClass method is not working ,